# iTunes 11 does not record Play Counts anymore?

Tags: itunes, macos, music

I was playing an album the other day and noticed that none of the songs being played are incrementing their play count. I am running iTunes 11.0 and would like play counts to work like before.

What is happening and can I fix this?

Comment: I haven't experienced this with iTunes 11 on 10.7. I just tested by playing a song and the play count incremented as expected. That said, it could easily be an issue specific to 10.8 or some other quirk — iTunes 11 seems to be full of small issues that don't show up for everyone.

Comment: I have the same problem, it doesn't work with crossfade on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to some [articles](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20505863#20505863) I've read on the net, it's a design flaw by Apple - disabling crossfade will make the playcount start to work again.

Comment: Seems like Apple is facing some quality control issues

Comment: Can anyone tell if this is fixed in iTunes 11.0.1? An edit here once that is confirmed would be ideal.

Comment: @bmike not able to edit my question atm (out of town, terrible internet access) but if someone else verifies that upgrading the software works feel free to edit that in.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a universal glitch that's occurring with the new iTunes update they just had, seeing that this problem only showed up after the update.